# How to remove unwanted row spaces in a table in pptx using python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I would like to remove the unwanted spaces in between the rows so it becomes compact like below screencap:
[image]

I tried to use space_before and space_after but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

```
bdy_cells[i].text_frame.paragraphs[0].space_before = Pt(2)
bdy_cells[i].text_frame.paragraphs[0].space_after = Pt(2)
```

Shown below are the arrows which contains spaces

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-pptx` allows the `_Cell` margins to be specified: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#pptx.table._Cell.margin_top

So you might have something like:

```
from pptx.util import Inches

for cell in row.cells:
    cell.margin_top = Inches(0)
    cell.margin_bottom = Inches(0)
```

By default, the top and bottom cell margins are 0.05 inches.